# Can not build the android application after upgrading to flutter 3.0

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Command: flutter run --flavor dev --no-sound-null-safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script '/Users/petodavid/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevDebug'.

Process 'command '/Users/petodavid/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevDebug failed with exit code 1

I also created a github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103578

Comment: The only solution I found is to downgrade the flutter version to 2.10.5 using FVM